# Using AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioPlayer at the same time (or alternative ways of listening for sound and playing sound)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

Is there any reason why this wouldn't work?

I'm testing for sound in the microphone and playing a looping sound effect as I'm registering sound.

On the iPod touch this seems to work fine - on the iPhone though the sound effect either doesn't play at all, or is very quiet.

Any ideas? Or any alternative?

Thanks

Comment: Its possible that the iPhone is playing the sound through the earpiece rather than the loudspeaker. Can you verify this?

Comment: yeah, it is - only when I'm recording though. When I'm playing the sound without the recorder then it plays through the loudspeaker... how do I fix this?? thanks

Comment: That might be an anti-feedback feature.

Comment: yeah, you're right peter. Once I'd output it through the speaker using the code below it got itself into a continuous loop and as such the whole thing didn't work. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for some reason had to put this code before I played the sound:

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
        AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);    
        UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
        AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
```

to stop it playing through the earpiece.

Comment: I was getting very quiet initial sound from AVAudioPlayer (possibly from the earpiece). I also have AVAudioRecorder. This snippet of code fixed it for me, even for when earphones are in use. Thanks.